# automatically rotate screen in android emulator

Tags: android, linux, testing, ipc

There are api calls to `activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation)` which perform a "soft" rotate, which is not a "hardware" rotate. In other words, it is different from manually pressing `Ctrl+F11/F12` to rotate the screen.

In testing of some applications, the behavior of the app could in fact differ due to this subtle difference. For example, `ConnectBot` crashes when I use the api call to rotate back and forth multiple times.

My question: how can we send host key events to the host emulator process?

UPDATE: I added calls to `instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: try keeping the device in landscape mode and change Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION whenever you want portrait. Its a hack but might work. In some devices it changes to portrait but in some it will stay as it is. So not sure if it will work

Comment: @nandeesh What is `Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION`, and where can I change it?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908048/enable-and-disable-auto-rotate-programatically).

Comment: @nandeesh Now I see what you are saying, but that actually is not a problem for me. That setting is used to allow/disallow rotation. I still need a way to do real, hardware rotation, one that is exactly the same as pressing `Ctrl+F11`.