# Is it possible to change orientation of device when default device rotation is off?

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I am using an application for meditation on daily basis, today i was surprised by it because when i rotate screen, App goes to landscape mode, Although the Automatic rotation was off from my settings, How it can happen?

**Is there something like Force device to change orientation?**

And **If default device rotation is off then how app can know that device orientation is changed?**

I double checked my phones settings of Auto-Rotation and they were off.I am using Kitkat device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908048/enable-and-disable-auto-rotate-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file set activity tag, `screenOrientation` attribute  to `fullSensor` like this:

```
<activity
android:name=".MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can.

in `onCreate` method type

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

this will do the magic.