# Application enables orientation change button is status bar

Tags: android, nativescript

I use nativescript in my project, also I always disable toggler on status bar menu on my Galaxy Alpha that allows orientation change. When I open my app the button status is set to enabled. How to remove this behaviour?

Here is an example of what button i mean, on this screen it called auto rotation. https://lh4.ggpht.com/LuZ3y6wD4aUBdBvZ8Wxf73BpWdfbfNdxOVcHMuRVgRcyz-dl9rRNUwtpx-L9uPlgJdc=h900

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="org.nativescript.AzoftDeviceTracking"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="17"
            android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**
Ok, I found possible [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909079/2918518) but can't find it in nativescript code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this out, I used it in my project and it works fine

[npm nativescript-screen-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-screen-orientation)

Comment: I have no troubles with orientation changing.

Comment: Alright, just that when I added the package to my app and with the sample code on the package page, my app doesnt rotate even is the orientation status button is enabled or not. But if you think Im dont understand your question better yet, you might just wanna share a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I meant auto rotation button. It has no name on my phone.

Comment: Could share a screenshot?

Comment: I share the one, it not mine but the button is the same

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
import android.provider.Settings;
public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)
{
      Settings.System.putInt( context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Add permission to the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the excact same problem. What I ended up with was using an OrientationListener to detect when the user had actually tilted the phone to landscape and then setting the orientation to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR.

```
OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(getActivity()) {
@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    int epsilon = 10;
    int leftLandscape = 90;
    int rightLandscape = 270;
    if(epsilonCheck(orientation, leftLandscape, epsilon) ||
       epsilonCheck(orientation, rightLandscape, epsilon)){
            getMainActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        }
    }

    private boolean epsilonCheck(int a, int b, int epsilon) {
        return a > b - epsilon && a < b + epsilon;
    }
};
orientationEventListener.enable();
```

You would also need to add checks for portrait , because you described needing that in your original post.