# How to "Change Screen Orientation Settings of whole device"?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I want to change the screen orientation settings of android devices from my app from any mode to "**Auto Rotate**". This change is not only for my app but for whole device. I have "**Root Access**" also but if this thing is possible without root access then it will be much better. There are already apps in playstore like "**Rotation Control**" which does this stuff but I have no idea how it works and I am only getting docs and tutorials to change screen orientation at application level but I want at **device level**. So at least please guide me a bit or any idea would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any sense in putting this question on hold as user has already got the answer and a similar thread already exist on stackoverflow and without any hold. Please use your mod rights wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)
    {
          Settings.System.putInt( context.getContentResolver(), 
          Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

dont forget to add permissons

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

for more details you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908048/enable-and-disable-auto-rotate-programmatically)

Comment: But what about the Boolean Parameter? I should pass True or False?

Answer (score 0):

Set orientation permission in the manifest :

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

then enable the orientation by calling `setRequestedOrientation`:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: it will work only for my app or will apply for all apps?

Comment: this will work only for the current activity

Comment: yeah i checked.